# Titanium vs-code extension Log level trace is not working on Mac. How to view trace logs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

I downloaded the latest titanium extension for the vs-code on Mac.
Steps :

1. Focus on Titanium command view
2. Click on Set log level
3. Set log level to Trace
4. Run the project

The command that extension fires in the terminal doesn't contain any log level.

> appc run --platform ios --target simulator --device-id 1865408B-87E0-4ABC-9DAC-5737385D3165

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the global log-level with `ti config`:

`appc ti config cli.logLevel trace`

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Titanium+CLI+Options#TitaniumCLIOptions-cli.logLevel